# Feed json repsonse into google pie chart

Tags: json, jquery, google-visualization

I'm posting a form via ajax to a page (insert.php) which then returns a json formatted response. I want to use the json response to load a google pie chart. If I manually paste the json response into the new google.visualization.DataTable(), the chart is loaded, but when I try to feed the data to the drawChart function (below) nothing happens. I don't get any error messages.

I don't know if this is the right approach, so any help is much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#quiz").submit(function() { return false; });

    $("#send").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "insert.php",
      data : $("#quiz").serialize(),
      dataType: "json",
   success: function(jsonData){


drawChart(jsonData);

 }
})

 // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});



function drawChart(jsonData) {


  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}





});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not passing in the jsonData argument.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Should be

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```